# tokenはfilter_parametersに追加すべきですか？

Tags: ruby-on-rails

ユーザーを招待する機能を実装する際に、一意のtokenを発行しています。この場合、filter_parametersにtokenを追加してログに表示されないようにしたほうがいいでしょうか？

```
https://localhost:3000/users/invitation/accept?token=xxxxxx
```

したほうがいいとは思うのですが、ログはユーザーにはみれないし、パスワードやクレジットカードの情報じゃないからいいでしょって言われると、説得できず、ちょっと悩んでいます。

※ 招待メール内のtokenつきのURLにアクセスすると、パスワード設定画面がでて、アカウントが作成できます。

Answer (score 1):

招待されていない第三者がユーザーの招待をログから取得してアカウントを作成したときに、ユーザーを招待した人にとって不利益になることがあるのであれば、`filter_parameters`で隠したほうがいいと思います。

パスワードやクレジットカードの番号のように漏れると明らかに不利益になるのが分かるものだと説得もいらないでしょうが、分かりづらいと説得しづらそうですね。

ユーザーを招待した人に、招待していない第三者がアカウントを作成したことがわかってしまうと「気味が悪い」「個人情報が漏れているのではないか?」みたいに信用が落ちる可能性はありそうです。

一意のtokenをログに残す必要がないなら消してしまって問題になることはなさそうですし、
`filter_parameters`のドキュメントでは以下のようにあるので、`sensitive`だと思うものは全部filterしてしまって良いのではないでしょうか?

> Return a hash of parameters with all sensitive data replaced.
>   http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Http/FilterParameters.html#method-i-filtered_parameters